# Increase ramdrive memory for Hiren Boot CD

Tags: diagnostic, ramdisk

Does anyone know how to increase partition for Ramdrive R: for Hiren Boot CD ?

I installed a new Program with more than 64mb and I cannot run it.

By default it's size in 64mb.

IF not where I Could find a Norton Ghost that will be less than 64 mb?

Comment: A guess, maybe create a DOS bootable hirens cd and adjust it in the autoexec.bat file, change the size of XMSDSK.EXE...http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootablecd

Comment: Could you add this more detailed as an answer?